# how to get a variable dynamically from some table by connecting default database and use that variable in database.php file in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Hi we developed an application,in that one i want to give separate database for each registered users,whenever user register database should create automatically with their name and sql dump to that database,and also new database connection should establish for that db in database.php,how to get variable from a table (default database) to database.php file dynamically,i tried this one but got error **use** should not use in that database.php file

any help should appreciated,thanks in advance....

Comment: Can you explain what did you try and the received error?

Comment: <?php

use DB;
use Auth;
    
$san=DB::table('cities')->where('name',Auth::user()->branchname)->value('name');'mysql' => [
        
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => $san,
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
             ],                                                                                                           modified database.php like this

Comment: What's the error?